# Drupal - Handling dates

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal site and I add content with feeds module. The input file is a simple csv that has a date in the following format:

23-03-2015

My content type has a field of type "Date (ISO)".

I want to query the database and for that I'm using EntityFieldQuery. Here's a sample of my code:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'game_results')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_game_date', 'value', 'DESC')
  ->fieldCondition('field_division', 'tid', (array) $division)
  ->fieldCondition('field_season', 'tid', (array) $season)
  ->fieldCondition('field_hometeam', 'tid', (array) $team)
  ->fieldCondition('field_game_date', 'value', $gamedate, '<')
  ->range(1, $numberofgames)
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));

$result = $query->execute();
```

If I print the variable $gamedate, the output is "2015-03-29T00:00:00"

That code above gives me nodes where the 'field_game_date' is before $gamedate variable.

The problem is that drupal misses one of the most recent nodes.

If I have 5 nodes with date before $gamedate, it only returns the oldest 4.

I have a problem in my content type field properties? In my code? I need help on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: go to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/